# When fitting a Cox proportional hazards model, should we drop any observations that are right-censored at zero?

Tags: survival, cox-model, censoring

Consider the standard Cox proportional hazards setting with non-informative censoring. (See [https://web.stanford.edu/~lutian/coursepdf/unitcox1.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Elutian/coursepdf/unitcox1.pdf) for example.)

If our observations are triples $(Z_i, U_i, \delta_i)$, where $Z_i$ is a vector of covariates aka predictors, $U_i$ is the observed time, and $\delta_i = 0$ indicates that the observation is right-censored, should we drop any observations for which $U_i = 0$ and $\delta_i = 0$? In other words, would those observations have zero impact on the fitted Cox proportional hazards parameters? Intuitively, it would seem that we learn nothing from such an observation -- it is as if we didn't observe anything at all, since we already know that survival times must be non-negative.

If the Cox log-likelihood for coefficients $\beta$ is $\ln(L(\beta)) = \sum_i \delta_i \ln(h(u_i | z_i)) + \ln(S(u_i | s_i))$, where $h$ is the hazard and $S$ is the survival function, and $S(0) = 1$ does not vary with the coefficients $\beta$, it appears that observations right-censored at zero do not contribute to the gradient of the log likelihood with respect to $\beta$. Is that correct?